# Storing data in remote database using Android

Tags: android, database

I want to store some data in database remotely using android, e.g, I want to get value from text box view and store in database which isn't local to my android phone but rather it is located at some remote location.

What should I've to learn to do that, a sample code of that will be more than enough for me to understand and please do mention tutorial links or other helping material to understand how this can be done.

Comment: Simply you can create a db on server through web services you can insert and retrieve data.

Answer (score 1):

It seems people mainly use REST API to connect with android client to server and service-side language to communicate between server and database. When I learnt android, people suggest me learning node.js and express and later loopback to connect to database which I used was Mongodb. 
http://cwbuecheler.com/web/tutorials/2014/restful-web-app-node-express-mongodb/
I learnt node js and express through the tutorials on this website and I think this guide is quite comprehensive so I recommend it to you. 
If you prefer ignoring most part of server side, Mbaas, such as Parse, could be a good choice for you.
I am not sure about the best practice but I used node.js+express+mongodb+REST API to connect android application to server and am now learning loopback since it provides more features than express.

Comment: for server side DBMS which is best to use? Can we use sqlite for that purpose? and what if for testing/practice  purpose can i setup DBMS one my personal laptop?

Comment: It really depends on your need to choose the database. But it seems that nodejs express are mainly coupled with mongodb so I used it. For testing purpose, it is definitely ok to setup DBMS on your own laptop. When I wrote the application, I setup express and mongodb on my laptop to test. The above website also shows you how to setup server on your own computer if you choose to use nodejs.

Comment: Thank you very much bro and one last question, how much difficult all this, i don't have that much time i need to prepare my project asap which is about to store data on remotely located database. Again thank you very much ...

Comment: If you don't have much time, learning node.js+all this stuff is not suitable for you. But if you only need some simple storage of data, you may find some templates of node.js +express online related to REST API. If you need more complex storage, I would recommend Parse.

Comment: Also, if you use nodejs and express, you need something to turn REST API to java Interface. I used retrofit. You may have a look. http://square.github.io/retrofit/

Answer (score 0):

Because Android is not made to maintain connections open to remote database (you are not supposed to use JDBC), you need to use a web service, or API and send request to this webservice.

I really liked this post:
http://www.androidhive.info/2014/01/how-to-create-rest-api-for-android-app-using-php-slim-and-mysql-day-12-2/

But a google search on web services and Android will give you all you need.